# VC++ issue with output of date in Varient Structure

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hi my api from msdn is running but output is not in a proper format i use date type but it is showing me float values. I implemented API for Win32_NTLogEvent.

here is a sample code..

```
        VARIANT vtProp1;

        hres = pclsObj->Get(L"TimeGenerated", 0, &vtProp1, 0, 0);
        wcout << "Event Log time generated : " << vtProp.date << endl << endl ;

        VariantClear(&vtProp1);
```

and this is the output of it

Event Log time generated : 2.32679e-299

which is not in a date format.

Comment: First, your nuts for assuming the date member is valid without checking the vt member for a qualified VT_DATE. Second, once you have done that, you can simply convert to a string using `VariantChangeType` with `VT_BSTR` as the intended target type unless you want a specific date format, which gets considerably trickier. And honestly I think you would be happier using the `<comutil>` library and [`variant_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x295h94e.aspx)

Comment: Your assumption that the VARIANT contains a date is not correct.  Details are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237%28v=vs.85%29.aspx